# Xamarin forms app Number Problem. Emulator shows wrong number but physical phone shows true

Tags: android, xamarin, math, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I show "amount" (miktar on the picture). It's wrong on the emulator and this casue some problems to me while working on emulator but It's true on physical phone.

Emulator :

[image]

Physical Phone : [image]

```
var myServiceCall = await serviceManager.getHareketList();

            if (myServiceCall != null)
            {
                foreach (var response in myServiceCall)
                {
                    var myMiktar = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(response.MIKTAR), 2);
                    Console.WriteLine(myMiktar);
                    if (response.PARTI == null || response.PARTI == "null")
                    {
                        response.PARTI = "";
                    }
                    BarkodListItem b = new BarkodListItem(response.BARKOD, myMiktar.ToString(), response.SATIRNO, response.STOKKOD, response.sto_isim, response.PARTI, response.LOT, response.GRAF, response.CRAF);
                    MyBarkodList.Add(b);

                    OnPropertyChanged();

                }
            }
```

**var myMiktar = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(response.MIKTAR), 2);**

I use this code block to make convert.

That below string is what comes from my service. Phone shows this "1" but emulator shows 100000000.

> "MIKTAR":"1,00000000"

Comment: You need to be sure your phone and emulator are both using the same locale.  In the US locale comma is the thousands seperator, while most European locales treat it as a decimal seperator

Comment: Jason thanks for your answer. I checked my emulator locale from settings, its Turkey and I live in Turkey. It looks true.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to Jason's comment, as an answer:

> You need to be sure your phone and emulator are both using the same locale. In the US locale comma is the thousands seperator, while most European locales treat it as a decimal seperator.

For more info about locale, you can also refer to the official doc: [Android Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization#locale).